# how to use spring annotations like @Autowired or @Value in kotlin for primitive types?

Tags: spring, kotlin, autowired, kotlin-null-safety, kotlin-interop

Autowiring a non-primitive with spring annotations like bellow works:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var metaDataService: MetaDataService
```

But this doesn't work:

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
lateinit var cacheTimeSeconds: Int
```

Error:

> lateinit modifier is not allowed for primitive types.

How to autowire primitve properties into Kotlin classes?

Comment: Can you autowire the nullable version? And does the field have to be lateinit

Comment: Yes, var todCacheTimeSeconds: Int? = null works, but thats not what i want.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can also use the @Value annotation within the constructor:

```
class Test(
    @Value("\${my.value}")
    private val myValue: Long
) {
        //...
  }
```

This has the benefit that your variable is final and none-nullable. I also prefer constructor injection. It can make testing easier.

Answer (score 21):

> @Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
>   lateinit var cacheTimeSeconds: Int

should be

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
val cacheTimeSeconds: Int? = null
```

Comment: also u can inject `env` and pass values form there, using `lazy` delegate

Comment: I would advise against a nullable type, if possible (and not only because OP said that's not an option). Making something nullable that you didn't intend to make nullable by design is basically going backwards towards Java...

Answer (score 13):

I just used `Number` instead of `Int` like so:

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
lateinit var cacheTimeSeconds: Number
```

The other options are to do what others mentioned before:

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
var cacheTimeSeconds: Int? = null
```

Or you can simply provide a default value like:

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
var cacheTimeSeconds: Int = 1
```

In my case I had to get a property that was a `Boolean` type which is primitive in Kotlin, so my code looks like this:

```
@Value("\${myBoolProperty}")
var myBoolProperty: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set a default value

```
    @Value("\${a}")
    val a: Int = 0
```

in application.properties

```
a=1
```

in the code

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@Component
class Main : CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("\${a}")
    val a: Int = 0

    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        println(a)
    }
}
```

it will print `1`

or use contructor inject

```
@Component
class Main(@Value("\${a}") val a: Int) : CommandLineRunner {

    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        println(a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Without default value and outside constructor

From:

```
@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}") lateinit var cacheTimeSeconds: Int
```

---

To:

```
@delegate:Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")  var cacheTimeSeconds by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
```

Good Luck

[Kotlin doesn't have primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57408327/5279996)

Comment: OP says "Autowiring a non-primitive with spring annotations"...

Comment: @powermilk Could you share the property to try to deduce why it fails or reproduce? And also the full error

Comment: String is Object, not primitive. I know, there is only objects in Kotlin, but not for JVM. 

See example in OP: 

`@Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")
lateinit var cacheTimeSeconds: Int`

There is few solutions are given in this thread, but without default value and outside constructor you can do it in this way:

`@delegate:Value("\${cacheTimeSeconds}")  var cacheTimeSeconds by Delegates.notNull<Int>()`

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the annotation, but the mix of primitive and `lateinit`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761294/why-doesnt-kotlin-allow-to-use-lateinit-with-primitive-types), Kotlin does not allow `lateinit` primitives.

The fix would be to change to a nullable type `Int?`, or to not use `lateinit`.

[This *TryItOnline*](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/OSexuFjBWaGaKyexJDUzL7NEoSyxSCE5MTkjNSQzNzU4NTk/L6XYSsEzr4Sr9v9/AA) shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin compiles Int to int in java code. Spring wanted non-primitive types for injection, so you should use Int? / Boolean? / Long? and etc. Nullable types kotlin compile to Integer / Boolean / etc.