# Does Kotlin have primitive types?

Tags: kotlin, primitive-types, reference-type

Does Kotlin have primitive types?. When I declare the variable: `val myAge: Int = 18` then the `myAge` variable stores the actual values is `18` or stores the addresses of the objects in the memory?. If `Int` is primitive type then why we can use its method like `myAge.minus(10)`?

[image: Image source: stackoverflow.com]

Answer (score 46):

No... and yes.

Kotlin doesn't have primitive types (I mean you cannot declare primitive directly). It uses classes like `Int`, `Float` as an object wrapper for primitives.

When kotlin code is converted to JVM code, whenever possible, "primitive object" is converted to java primitive.
In some cases, this cannot be done. Those cases are, for example, collections of "primitives". For example, `List<Int>` cannot contain primitive. So, the compiler knows when it can convert an object to a primitive. And, again, it's very similar to Java:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>;

numbers.add(0); // <-- you use primitive, but in fact, JVM will convert this primitive to object.
numbers.add(new Integer(0)); // <-- We don't need do that.
```

Also, when you declare "nullable primitive" it is never converted to primitive (which is kind of obvious, as primitive cannot be `null`). In Java, it works very similarly:

```
int k = null; // No way!
Integer kN = null; // That's OK.
```

One more thing - what docs are saying about it?

> For Common, JVM, JS
>
> Represents a 32-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type int.
>
> For Native
>
> Represents a 32-bit signed integer.

@see: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html

So, the last conclusion. Kotlin doesn't have primitive types out of the box. You treat all objects like objects. Converting to primitive is done at some lower level than code. This design is caused to keep compatibility with JVM.

I did a little deep dive and published it on Medium. For interested: https://medium.com/@przemek.materna/kotlin-is-not-primitive-primitives-in-kotlin-and-java-f35713fda5cd

Comment: Mmm.  To put it more directly: **Kotlin the language doesn't have primitives; its implementations may use them where possible.**  On the JVM, that generally means where values are not nullable and not referenced.

Comment: Related to this topic and might be of interest, check `reflectClassUtil.kt:32` eg here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a07f455ae5936a341a3cd9fc29ce17e1dcbf127b/core/descriptors.runtime/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/descriptors/runtime/structure/reflectClassUtil.kt#L32

Comment: Usage of primitives in runtime is directly [stated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html) in the Kotlin documentation: _"In Kotlin, everything is an object in the sense that you can call member functions and properties on any variable. While certain types have an optimized internal representation as primitive values at runtime (such as numbers, characters, booleans and others), they appear and behave like regular classes to you."_

Answer (score 20):

Short answer - **yes** and depends on the declaration.

```
val myAge: Int = 18           // this is primitive
val myAge2: Int? = 18         // this is not
```

There's a very informative video about that
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ta5wBJsC39s

Comment: If `Int` is primitive type then why we can use its method like ```myAge.minus(10)?```

Comment: Minus actually is an operator function (`public operator fun minus(other: Int): Int`) meaning that it's the same as `myAge - 10`

Comment: Where you would declare this operator overloading method. Obviously inside class so how (Int) could be  primitive type.

Comment: @Demigod minus is an operator function means that it is implemented inside a class , and that class happens to be the Int class in this example.

Answer (score 3):

On the Java platform, numbers are physically stored as JVM primitive types, unless we need a nullable number reference (e.g. Int?) or generics are involved. In the latter cases numbers are boxed.

Note that boxing of numbers does not necessarily preserve identity:

```
val a: Int = 10000
println(a === a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

Note "===" used to compare reference ....

On the other hand, it preserves equality:

```
val a: Int = 10000
println(a == a) // Prints 'true'
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
println(boxedA == anotherBoxedA) // Prints 'true'
```

Comment: should be less than 128 - val a: Int = 100 to preserve equality. Please check docs

Answer (score 1):

Document say (For Int type):

For Common, JVM, JS:
"Represents a 32-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type int."

For Native:
"Represents a 32-bit signed integer."

I tested it (I think these codes run on jvm), and you can see the results in these images. The results were similar for float, double, and other data types.

[image]

[image]