# Kotlin: Hashcode of chars is same as ASCII value

Tags: kotlin, hash, char, standard-library

I noticed that the hashcode of Char-values is exactly the ID they have in ASCII, for example:

```
println('a'.hashCode()) //is 97
```

Is this true by contract and where can I see the implementation for this? The class Any.kt doesn't contain the implementation and Char.kt does neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the hashcode of Char-values is exactly the ID they have in ASCII […]

That is impossible. ASCII only has 128 values, but Kotlin `Char` has 65536, so clearly, a `Char` cannot have their ASCII value as their hashcode, because 99.8% of them don't *have* an ASCII value.

> Is this true by contract

No, it is not. The contract for [`kotlin.Char.hashCode()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/hash-code.html) is:

> ## `fun hashCode(): Int`
>
> Returns a hash code value for the object. The general contract of `hashCode` is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the object is modified.
> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals()` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

That is the whole contract. There is nothing about a relationship with ASCII.

> and where can I see the implementation for this? The class Any.kt doesn't contain the implementation and Char.kt does neither.

I am assuming types like [`kotlin.Char`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char) or [`kotlin.Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int) are not actually implemented as Kotlin objects but as compiler intrinsics for performance reasons. For example, I would expect `42` to be a JVM `int` on the JVM platform and an ECMAScript `number` on the ECMAScript platform, and not implemented as a full-blown object with object header, instance variable table, class pointer, etc.

As it so happens, Kotlin's contract for `hashCode()` matches the contract for pretty much every other language as well, so I would expect that they as much as possible re-use the underlying platform's implementation. (In fact, I would suspect that is precisely the reason for designing the contract this way.)

Even for Kotlin/Native, it makes sense to map `kotlin.Int` to a native machine integer `int_fast32_t` or `int32_t` type.

Comment: On the JVM, `Char` and `Int` (along with `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Long`, `Float`, and `Double`) are compiled down to [primitive values](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/primitive-data-types-and-their-limitations.html) where possible — but it's not always possible, e.g. where they need to be nullable, used as generic types in collections, or for interoperability with Java objects.  In those cases, the values are ‘boxed’ into wrapper objects; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408327/does-kotlin-have-primitive-types)… (contd)

Comment: It may well be that Sun deliberately chose the hash codes of those wrappers to match the primitive values, to reduce one of the gotchas with autoboxing.  (There are several more, though.)  But if it ain't in the contract, then you shouldn't rely on it.