# How to avoid or fix Kotlin warning related with Int vs Integer

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot 2.0.0 / Kotlin / Gradle project.
I have a warning while injecting integers. I know the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769161/819651) but don't know the fix. Is there a better way to inject these `@Value`s?
Thanks

Warning:

```
\src\main\kotlin\com\tech\stands\PicturesDownloader.kt: (22, 31): This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.Int instead.
```

Code:

```
abstract class PicturesDownloader {

    @Value("\${cache.adpics.concurrent}")
    lateinit var MAX_CONCURRENT: Integer
    @Value("\${cache.adpics.max}")
    lateinit var MAX_AD_PICS: Integer
}
```

If there's no way to fix, is there way to suppress it?

Comment: that would say: `'lateinit' modifer is not allowed on properties of primitive types`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to suppress it, you can use this annotation:

```
@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")
```

---

I'm not familiar with Spring Boot and the value injection system, so I'm not sure if this will work. Set the value to 0, use `Int` and remove lateinit. As it's still a var, it can still be set after creation, meaning the value injection should be able to set it once the class is created.

```
@Value("\${cache.adpics.concurrent}")
var MAX_CONCURRENT: Int = 0
```