# What Kotlin type to use for lateinit Int value

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin does not allow this:

```
private lateinit var port: Int;
```

What can I use to mark an integer like value as allow to lateinit?

I understand *why* this does not work (Int is primitive), I need to know *what to use instead*?

**Edit 1**

It's not a duplicate of this because I want to know what to use in this case, not why it's happening: [Why doesn't Kotlin allow to use lateinit with primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761294)

**Edit 2**
As suggested by @Roland below - BitInteger works for me:

```
private lateinit var port: BigInteger;
```

I'm justing using it to generate a URL so I really only need it in a String concatenation.

Comment: Hm, what a seemingly arbitrary limitation. As if `Int?` was disallowed.

Comment: You can't lateinit nullable types, so `Int?` does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Kotlin allow to use lateinit with primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761294/why-doesnt-kotlin-allow-to-use-lateinit-with-primitive-types)

Comment: @marstran - Not a duplicate, I **specifically said** that I understand why it does not work, and that question answers that nicely.  I want to know *what to do instead*.

Comment: You can't use `lateinit` so you must initialize it.

Comment: you could wrap it, if you really want to keep `Int` and do not want a default value... or use some other type, e.g. `BigInteger`? ;-)

Comment: if you are doing `String` concatenation, I would probably rather stick to `Int?` instead... or maybe even `lateinit String` and check the input instead...

Answer (score 8):

Some variants come to my mind, but depending on how you use it later on, none might be suitable to you.

1. just use a default value, e.g.:

   ```
   var port : Int = 8080
   ```
2. use some other `Number`-type instead of `Int`, e.g.

   ```
   class Server {
     lateinit var port : Number
   }
   ```

   You can then call `port.toInt()` if you need to. But: there are a lot of `Number`-types, so narrowing it down to e.g. `BigInteger` might make sense. Otherwise you might get objects, you do not want to accept in the first place.
3. using `Delegates.notNull`

   ```
   var port : Int by Delegates.notNull()
   ```

   but: even though you spare your `null`-value then, you can't check whether the variable has been initialized, so you just have to deal with an exception as soon as you want to access it... not very nice I think... but if you are sure you get a value, then that might be ok for you too.
4. just use `Int?` and skip the `lateinit`, e.g.:

   ```
   class Server {
     var port : Int? = null
   }
   ```

   Instead of `::port.isInitialized` you would ask for `port != null`, but: you need to handle the possible `null`-value now, but with `?` that shouldn't be such a big problem.
5. use `Int?` with `Delegates.vetoable` in case you do not want to accept `null`-values after you got your first value, making it basically something like `lateinit` ;-)

   ```
   class Server {
     var port : Int? by Delegates.vetoable(null as Int?) {
       _, _, newValue -> newValue != null
     }
   }
   ```

   and check again using `port != null`, which now behaves similar to `::port.isInitialized`

Not that I am a big fan of the last two as they introduce `null` again, but depending on what you do, that might be perfectly ok...

As you added something regarding `String` concatenation, I would even more so use `Int?` here. You can then still use something like:

```
url = "$host${port?.let { ":$it" }?:""}"
// or:
url = port?.let { "$host:$it" } ?: host
// or
url = listOfNotNull(host, port).joinToString(":")
```

The same can't be really easier with the `::port.isInitialized`?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the perfect solution you are looking for, but i do it like this (in case you are actually forced to use a primitive type):

```
 class Example{
    private var _port: Int? = null

    var port:Int
         get() = this._port!!
         set(i) { _port = i }
    }
```

At least this allows you to use the property as if was not nullable.
Best solution we found for us so far!

Comment: See my edit, I actually changed it to `BigInteger` instead, and it works fine for me (I'm using it for generating a URL so I just convert it to string).  Perhaps I could use BigInteger and cast it if I needed the actual `Int` value.

Comment: @mikeb yeah i saw that, but i expect that in some cases you can't do such a workaround

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not cross-platform, the obvious solution would be

```
@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN") lateinit var i: java.lang.Integer
```

which has one-to-one correspondence with `Int` values (unlike `BigInteger`).