# How to achieve lateinit effect for primitive types?

Tags: kotlin

I've read [Why doesn't Kotlin allow to use lateinit with primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761294/why-doesnt-kotlin-allow-to-use-lateinit-with-primitive-types).

However, there is a benefit of using the `lateinit`, that is, if the error is caused by no initialization, it can be immediately known from the error message. But for primitive types that cannot use `lateinit`, such as Int, the user have to assign a value of 0. But if the appropriate value should be a value that is much greater than 0 and must be determined later, and then, the user forgot to init the value, the program produced an error later, **is there any way to make the user who read the error message immediately realize that the error is not caused by other reasons**?

thanks a lot.

And `lateinit var v:Int? = null` is very bad, which makes operations like `v--` become very complex.

Comment: "makes operations like `v--` become very complex." No it doesn't. Just do `v!!.dec()`, and you get an exception (just like you do with a `lateinit`, though not the same exception) if you try to access an uninitialised property.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for your answers, but it seems that `--` is not equivalent to `.dec()`. https://pl.kotl.in/QOwpjZCpt

Comment: Reference types have a very obvious and unambiguous value for 'not set': null.  That's not the case for primitives.  (Zero may well be a valid value.  As may -1, or -9999, or even MIN_VALUE, or MAX_VALUE...  And what about other primitive types?  What would be the placeholder character?  Or boolean?  Whichever value you pick, someone will need it at some point.  Or you have an instance-specific placeholder, which would be even more complicated than a wrapper.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer linked by you explains why it is technically impossible to support lateinit for primitive types. So even if there are benefits of having them, then... well, see above, it is technically impossible.

You can use a property delegate for a very similar effect:

```
var v by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will make `v--` unusable, but this might be the best answer? Orz

Comment: Hmm, why unusable? I tested this and both `v--` and `--v` seem to work as expected. @ltoibq93578

Comment: when the version of kotlin is 1.3.72 it will cause CompilationException. But 1.5 will not.